# Is the Windows 10 upgrade still available after restoring to the factory restore point?

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, restore

I have a Dell Alienware 13 laptop that's been having some issues after the Windows 10 upgrade. After attempting to solve this issue in many ways, I've decided to restore to my laptop's factory state, running Windows 8 using the `AlienRespawn` program.

Will I still be able to upgrade to Windows 10 after performing this action?

Comment: It depends if the system was configured with an OEM build of Windows 10 or not.  Unless the system is very new, probably not..  It would probably install Windows 7 or 8 and then you would have to upgrade to Win 10..

Comment: **Yes**;  Once Windows 10 has been activated on a machine it will automatically activate.  It isn't clear what version of Windows you are currently using, please clarify the question, so that is clear.

Comment: @Ramhound Edited.

Comment: So it currently is running Windows 10?  Just download the `Media Creation Tool`, and just perform a clean install, if asked for a product key just skip that step.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't have, and can't get an Internet connection.

Comment: ....You can download the .ISO on any computer, create the bootable media, then use that.  Since your installation I assume is activated, a clean install from this point out, will automatically activate.